# How to display the Rectangles from different frames in one frame?

Tags: image-processing, matlab-cvst

I am working on a vacant spot detection solution. I am getting the rectangle boxes for different frames in multiples figures, all I want is to display all the detected rectangles boxes in single figure.

Here I am attaching the figures Please find the attachment

Image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L48y3.jpg)      Image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5JFV.jpg)